# Where does the “… take Manhattan” trope originate?

Tags: etymology

There are a number of creative works whose titles end in this way. For example,

- *The Muppets Take Manhattan*, a 1984 film
- “First We Take Manhattan”, a 1987 song
- *Friday the 13th Part VIII: Jason Takes Manhattan*, a 1989 film
- “The Angels Take Manhattan”, a 2012 episode of *Doctor Who*

What is the antecedent of these “take[s] Manhattan” titles?

Comment: I think it is the phrase "We will take Manhattan by storm" as an analogy for having a hit play on Broadway.

Comment: I wouldn't say these productions are following a trope; Manhattan is a frequent subject of popular culture and the sense of *take* is conventional: *[take](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)* (MW) is *3. a:  to catch or attack through the effect of a sudden force or influence; b: to catch or come upon in a particular situation or action; c: to gain the approval or liking of :  captivate, delight.*

Comment: A useful link : http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Humanities/2009_March_20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase *take Manhattan* appears to reference the song *Manhattan* by Rogers & Hart, first heard in the [*Garrick Gaieties*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Garrick_Gaieties) from 1925.

The line in the [original](http://www.lorenzhart.org/manhattansng.htm) is *We'll have Manhattan, the Bronx and Staten Island too ...* [*lorenzhart.org*]

[Later renditions](http://www.spiritofsinatra.com/pages/Lyrics/m/Manhattan.htm) changed that line (among others) to *I'll take Manhattan, ...* [spiritofsinatra.com]

It also has overtones of the military meaning of *[take](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/take)*

> Capture or gain possession of by force or military means:
>
> *twenty of their ships were sunk or taken*
>
> *the French took Ghent* [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

The phrase, *I'll take Manhattan ...* has become a meme, giving rise to a number of other works, as discussed by the original poster.

Comment: A trope is a figure of speech. Here to take is used with the name of a town in military sense - quite a normal thing.